# How can I use Git to see in which commits a file was renamed?

Tags: git, version-control

I don't want to see the whole history or diffs (so `git log --follow filename` is not I'm looking for).

I want to find out the commit ids in which a file might have been renamed, in order to figure out the date & time of the changes.

Can git do this? My Google Fu is weak, I couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
git log --name-status --follow --diff-filter=R -- new_filename
```

`--diff-filter=R` matches commits which have renamed files. `--follow` and the new filename are also necessary. Without `--follow`, the commit that has the renaming is excluded.

Comment: Awesome, I had missed `--name-status`, that was the missing piece to be able to find what I wanted. Thanks a lot!